# Python Requests API sequential run

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm fairly new to Python and I was able to run a python request and grabbed the session token and saved it to a variable, Now I'm trying to pass that session to a new request but I'm not sure how can I API request sequentially right after one another?
this is my request ..

```
url = "https://1.1.1.1/jsonrpc"


payload = json.dumps(
  
  {
  "session": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "method": "exec",
  "params": [
    {
      "url": "sys/login/user",
      "data": [
        {
          "user": "admin",
          "passwd": "password"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)


response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, verify=False)
s = (response.json())
print (s['session'])
```

now I want to pass 's' variable to a new API request in the same .py file but not sure how to run them right after each other.

```
url = "https://1.1.1.1/jsonrpc"

payload = json.dumps({
  "session": s
  "id": 1,
  "method": "set",
  "params": [
    {
      "url": "/dvmdb/adom",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "NEW_ADOM"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: You just code one after the other. Have you have a problem doing that?

Comment: That is completely up to the site you are talking to, which you have not shown.  Your code  is probably right, except that you need a comma after the `s`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `s` in two separated functions, you can declare `s` variable outside those two functions and change that via `global` keyword

```py
s = None
def get_session():
    ...
    global s
    s = response.json()['session']
```

Then you can use `s` in another function